# When a curve is future (past) inextendible?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, causality, topology

Future (past) endpoint: We say that $p\in M$ is a future (past) endpoint of a curve $\lambda$ if for every neighborhood $O$ of $p$ there exists a $t_0$ such that

$\lambda(t)\in O$ for all $t>t_0$ (future endpoint)

$\lambda(t)\in O$ for all $t<t_0$ (past endpoint)

Future(past) inextendible: The curve $\lambda$ is future (past) inextendible if it has no future (past) endpoint.

**My question is**: If it has no endpoint why it is called inextendible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purposes of this question I will focus only for the future endpoint. With these types of definitions, it is very instructive to work with simple examples. Consider a curve $\lambda:I_1 \mapsto U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ where our manifold is just the real line. Suppose the curve is parametrised by $t$. Take $I_1 = [0,1]$. Now this curve will have $p = \lambda(t = 1)$ as its endpoint. To see this let $\mathcal{O} = \lambda(t)$ for $t \in (1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$. Clearly $\mathcal{O}$ is a neighbourhood of $p$. Furthermore, for any $\epsilon$, we can choose a $t_0$ such that it is arbitrarily close to 1 and therefore $\lambda(t_0) \in \mathcal{O}$.

Let's try to do the same for another subset where this time we have $I_2 = [0,1)$ and $\lambda:I_2 \mapsto U$. However, this time we don't have a future endpoint! As whatever point we choose as a potential future endpoint, we can always choose another point that is arbitrarily close to $t = 1$! Furthermore, $p = \lambda(t = 1)$ cannot be a future endpoint as $t = 1$ is not included in $I_2$.

To see why $I_2$ has a future endpoint but not $I_1$, define a new parameter $\tau$:

$$ \tau = tan\left( \frac{\pi}{2} t\right)$$

It is easy to check that for $I_2$, $\tau \in [0, \infty)$. With this parametrisation of the curve it is clear why $I_2$ has no endpoint as it goes on forever! You can't do the same mapping with $I_1$ as $tan(\pi/2)$ is not defined. Therefore, with $I_1$ you will always hit the endpoint given enough time. This means you can extend it once you hit the endpoint. For the other one however, there is no endpoint to hit and you cannot extend it.